# How to know who is the owner of a window

Tags: c#, wpf

I am inside of a window class and i want to communicate with his owner class like:

```
    public partial class window2 : Window {
    window1 w1= new window1();
    w1=ownerWindow??;
}
```

It is oriented to events, where the window1 is sending a class to window2. Does it exist something like ownerWindow, or how does it work?

Answer (score 2):

Use the the [Owner](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.owner(v=vs.110).aspx) property.

```
var owner = Window.Owner;
```

If you create any windows, be sure to set it:

```
var w = new Window { Owner = this };
```